Possible gaps for a function and its Fourier transform
This is another question on the possible shape of sets $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}^d,d\geq 2,$ where resp. a non-null Schwarz function $f$ and its Fourier transform can vanish.
A nice remark by Christian Remling on Can a function and its Fourier transform both vanish on a convex cone? is that choosing separable functions yields that both functions can vanish on a half-space. The theorem by Shapiro mentioned there says that $A$ and $B$ cannot be resp. a "major convex cone" (strictly larger than a half space) and a non-empty open set.
Hence a remaining question is what can happen if $A$ is a "minor cone", say the quadrant of points with non-negative coordinates. As we saw, $B$ can be a half-space, but not a major cone. Is it possible that $B$ has a "gap in each coordinate"?
Here is a one-sentence question: is it possible to find a non-null Schwartz function $f$ on $\mathbb R^2$ which vanishes on a quarter-space and which Fourier transform $\hat f(x,y)$ vanishes for $x\in O$ or $y\in O'$ where $O$, $O'$ are non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb R$?

I don't understand your question: Christian Remling's comment which you referred to points out that if $g$ and $\hat h$ both vanish on a half-line, then $f(x,y) := g(x),h(y)$ vanishes on a half-plane and $\hat f$ also does. But vanishing on a half-plane is stronger than vanishing on a quarter-plane, so it seems to me that this $f$ exactly answers the question of your last paragraph.

Yes but vanishing on OxO' is stronger (or at least different) than vanishing on a half plane

Now I'm even more confused. Vanishing on $O\times O'$ with $O,O'$ nonempty open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ just means the same as vanishing on a nonempty open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$, since the former are a basis of the latter; and anyway the half-plane we're talking about is of the form $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{\gt 0}$.  What more do you want?

Sorry, what I meant by "vanishes on a gap for each coordinate" came out completely wrong, I actually meant that it should vanish on infinite vertical and horizontal gaps, the post edited.

Ok, I think I managed to prove that the answer is no for the discrete version, I put it here for anyone interested (likely generalises to any dimension, didn't look into the continuous version).
Assume $ \psi \subset L^{2}(  \mathbb  T  ^{2})$ has a gap in each coordinate, i.e. vanishes on $T_\varepsilon^c$ where $ T_{\varepsilon }:=(  \mathbb  T   \setminus [-\varepsilon ,\varepsilon ])^{2}$ for some $ \varepsilon >0.$
Then if  $ \hat \psi $ vanishes on a quarter space, then $ \psi \equiv 0$.
Let us write the proof by contradiction. Assume wlog that $  \hat \psi $ vanishes on $ (-\mathbb{N}^{*})^{2}$ and that $ \hat \psi (0,0)\neq 0.$
Let $ C_{\varepsilon } \subset  \mathbb C $ the unit circle except points of angle in $ [-\varepsilon ,\varepsilon ]$. According to Mergelyan's theorem, there are polynomials $P_{n}( z)\to z^{-1}$ uniformly on $  C_{\varepsilon }$. Putting $ Q_{n}( u)=e^{iu}P_{n}( e^{iu}),$ $ Q_{n}( u)\to 1$ on $  \mathbb  T   \setminus [-\varepsilon ,\varepsilon ]$, hence $$  Q_{n}(u)Q_{n}(v)\psi (u,v)\to \psi (u,v)$$ in $ T_{\varepsilon } $, hence on  $ L^{2} (  \mathbb  T  ^{2})$ because $ \psi \equiv 0$ on $ T_{\varepsilon }^c$, and $ \hat \psi  \star(  \hat  Q_{n} \otimes \hat  Q_{n})\to \hat \psi $ in $ L^{2}( \mathbb{Z} ^{2})$.
Therefore, since $ Q_{n}( u)=\sum_{m>0}a_{m} e^{imu}, \hat Q_{m}=\sum_{m>0}a_{m}\delta _{m}$,
\begin{align*}
0\neq \hat \psi ( 0,0)=\lim_n\sum_{k,l\in \mathbb{Z} ^{2}}\underbrace{ \hat \psi ( k,l)  }_{=0\text{ if }k<0,l<0}\underbrace{ \hat Q_{n}(- k) \hat Q_{n}( -l)}_{=0\text{ if }k\geqslant0\text{ or }l\geqslant0}=0.
\end{align*}
